# GCC Compiler Refuses To See Main Method (C Programming)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, sdl

I recently downloaded the AGIL adventure game interpreter from: http://www.agidev.com/dl_files/agil-0.1.5.tar.gz

It is a C program which runs old Sierra adventure games like King's Quest.

I have being trying to compile the source code so that I can debug it and learn how it works.

However despite my best efforts the GCC compiler never sees the main method, despite its existence.

Here is the compiler output:

```
make linsdl all 
make -fMakefile.sdl
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/alay/Downloads/AGIL/agil'
gcc -O -Wall -Isrc/include -I/usr/local/include -DTARGET_SDL -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -pedantic -I/usr/local/include/SDL -Dmain=SDL_main -c src/main.c -o bin/main.o
gcc -O -Wall -Isrc/include -I/usr/local/include -DTARGET_SDL -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -pedantic -I/usr/local/include/SDL -Dmain=SDL_main -c src/drivers/sdl.c -o bin/driver.o
gcc -L/usr/local/lib bin/main.o bin/general.o bin/event.o bin/graphics.o bin/menu.o bin/text.o bin/resource.o bin/gameid.o bin/pic_op.o bin/picture.o bin/lzw.o bin/vm.o bin/actionop.o bin/testop.o bin/status.o bin/object.o bin/view.o bin/check.o bin/save.o bin/message.o bin/sound.o bin/decomp.o bin/driver.o \
        -o bin/agil -lm  -lSDLmain -lSDL -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alay/Downloads/AGIL/agil'
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [linsdl] Error 2
```

The only changes I made were to change include statements so that the compiler could find the SDL library. For example I changed: `#include "SDL.h"` to `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`.

My goal is to understand the C code so that I can build something similar on another platform.

Comment: Which file contains `main()` ?

Comment: what you meant by this `-Dmain=SDL_main` in your Makefile

Answer (score 1):

The `-Dmain=SDL_main` is equivalent to having a `#define main SDL_main` in your code. The preprocessor will replace the main with SDL_main, and the linker won't find it ( because it itn't there).

Run `gcc -E ...` and see how the code looks after the preprocessor ran, but before it goes to the compiler.

LE: True. But I wouldn't pass it as argument to gcc ( and changing the header files ). But it as a define after the includes.

Also run a locate libsdl and check you pass the path correctly to the linker.

Comment: From what I understand, the SDL libraries are supposed to provide the true `main` (which in turns, calls `SDL_main`);